# UIPath - Retry Scope ignored when Global hander is present

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I have a UI Path process that interacts with a very dynamic webpage.

I added the global handler in order to send an email with a screenshot whenever something completely unexpected happens and that works fine, the trouble is I've caught several known problems with try-catch activities and retry scopes.

The global handler will retry a single activity, but sometimes the loop will need to go re-do a previous activity.

This happens with Try-Catch as well. Rather than handling the exception in the try-catch, it goes to the global handler.

After adding the global handler, the retry loop stops working. When it runs into an error, even when the condition is met, it doesn't retry like it did before, it simply jumps out to the global handler.

Is this by design, a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Just a note: I've worked around it by jury-rigging a do-while loop and adding a ton of element exists. Just curious why retry and try catch don't function with a global handler as it states it does in the documentation.
[image: This is what I want to have happen]

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: Maybe you show us how far you got? Not sure if I understood to 100%. But sounds interesting, at least ;)

Comment: It's not terribly complicated. I've noticed this happens with a try catch also.  I have a section that is prone to failure, but can be recovered. If it hits the error you'd expect the try-catch to work, instead it goes to the global handler workflow.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, show some screenshots. I think you use try catch in a wrong way. And maybe create a flowchart about what happens and what is currently happen wrong.

Comment: Again, it's really not complicated, added what I want vs what is happening.